# Is it 'more rigorous' to perform definite integrations, rather than indefinite integration while solving ODEs?

Tags: integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

In the beginning of my ODE course, my professor said something about performing definite integrations being 'more rigorous' than indefinite ones somehow, but also that it really wasn't much important, as both ones worked for the same problems.

I remember he gave an example like the following:

> Consider the simple differential equation
>   $$
> x'=g(t),\quad x(\tau)=\xi.
> $$
>
> Then, integrating from $\tau$ to $t$, we have
>
> $$
> x(t)-\xi=\int_\tau^tg(s)ds \iff x(t)=\xi+\int_\tau^tg(s)ds
> $$
>
> And we have our solution.
>
> Note that if we performed an indefinite integration, we wouldn't have gotten a solution, but many 'candidates'.

My questions  are:

1. How right is my professor, in terms of the 'rigorousity'?
2. What allows one to change $t\mapsto s$, before integrating?

Comment: For 2, why can't you write $x'(s)=g(s)$ instead of $x'(t)=g(t)$?

Comment: The point about changing $t$ to $s$ is that you don't want the same variable to do two different jobs in the same equation.  Since you're already using $t$ as an actual variable (in $x(t)$ and the bounds of integration) you need a different name for the dummy variable of integration.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "rigor" is merely showing me that your solution for $x$ has $x(\tau)=\xi$ and $x'(t)=g(t)$. Rigor doesn't really care how you found that $x$.

Comment: It's not more rigorous but it can be cleaner to use definite integrals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is perfectly alright to do an indefinite integral, as long as you don't forget the $+C$ and the initial condition.

For concreteness, take the following equation:

$$x'(t) = 2t, \ \ x(2) = 5$$

Performing an indefinite integral on $x'(t) = 2t$ gives $x(t) = \int 2t\ dt = t^2 + C$, where $C$ is an unkown constant. Now we plug in the initial condition: $x(2) = 2^2 + C = 4 + C = 5$, so $C = 1$. The complete solution is $x(t) = t^2 + 1$, which we could also have gotten via the definite integral route. As far as I can tell, neither method is more rigorous than the other, and neither one is really easier. Arguably the indefinite integral way has the advantage that it gives half a result when you don't have an initial condition, while the definite integral doesn't work.

Comment: One advantage of the definite integral approach is that there are occasions when you integrate from a constant time to $t$ with an integrand that also depends on $t$. For instance this occurs when you use Green's functions. Another advantage is that an indefinite integral does not really furnish any recipe for numerical computation, so if you encounter an ODE that can only be solved in terms of non-elementary integrals, the definite integral approach gives a way of numerically computing the solution (with just quadrature methods, not ODE methods).

Comment: Also, sometimes the definite integral approach makes the dependence of the solution on the initial conditions very simple and explicit from the beginning, whereas the indefinite integral approach may require some additional algebra. For instance this happens with first order linear equations being solved by the method of integrating factors. On the other hand, an advantage of a more "indefinite" approach is that you can separate the problem of finding the form of the general solution from the problem of finding how the constants depend on the initial condition.

Comment: Even without an initial condition, we can still use definite integrals to get $x(t) = x(0) + \int_{0}^{t}x'(\tau)\,d\tau$ $= x(0) + \int_{0}^{t}2\tau\,d\tau$ $= x(0)+t^2$, which is just as good as getting $t^2+C$.

Answer (score 4):

Your professor's definition of "rigorous" is a personal one.

All his example does is use the explicit condition supplied.  It's no more rigorous that integrating the general form with the arbitrary constant and calculating the value of the arbitrary constant from the given condition then.

However I would take the view that such convenient forms of solution do not generally provide themselves with differential equations.  In these cases you often have to work out the general form.  The arbitrary constant may even give the solution a "symmetry" or "shape" that an attempt to bypass that point will miss, even after you calculate the particular value for the constant in a particular case.  Seeing the general shape is often a significant factor in extending and improving physical theories.